# log4j rootlogger turn off logger for some classes

Tags: java, log4j

how can i configure a log4j.properties with a `rootlogger = debug, stdout, logfile` 
and `org.apache.httpclient = debug` which goes into the logfile but not the stdout?

raising the rootlogger to info is not acceptable as i have others package at the debug level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the `log4j.properties` file, add the line

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.httpclient=DEBUG, logfile
```

to direct the `org.apache.httpclient` logger output to the `logfile` appender.

Also include the line

```
log4j.additivity.org.apache.httpclient=false
```

to prevent the `org.apache.httpclient` logger output going to the `rootLogger`'s appenders.

Answer (score 0):

Your could achieve this functionality by using filters on the different appenders.  I think the [LevelRangeFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelRangeFilter.html) would be what you are looking for.

However I think filters can only be specified if your are using an xml file for configuration and are not supported when using a .properties file.

Comment: you mean the appender threshold ?